# Magento - Can I JSON encode the entire product collection?

Tags: php, ajax, magento

This is what I have so far.  Does it look relavent?  Or is there an easier way?

```
protected function _encodedProductCollection()
{
    $productcollection = $this->_getProductCollection();
    $productmodel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $categorymodel = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');

    $collection_to_encode = array();

    foreach( $productcollection as $product )
    {
        $product_to_encode = array();

        $thisproduct = $productmodel->load($product->getId());
        $productsname = $thisproduct->getName();
        $productsid = $thisproduct->getId();
        $productcategories = $thisproduct->getCategoryIds();
        $productscategoryname = $categorymodel->load($productcategories[0])->getName();  //we'll start with the first category name.
        //$productsimageurl = $thisproduct->getImageUrl();  //gets the image url if we need it later
        //$altcategorymethod = ($thisproduct->getCategory() ? $thisproduct->getCategory()->getName() : 'No Category');  //we may use this one instead.



        $product_to_encode[] = array(
            'id' => $productsid,
            'name' => $productsname,
            'category' => $productscategoryname );

        array_merge($product_to_encode, $collection_to_encode); 
    }

    $encoded_products = json_encode($collection_to_encode);

    return $encoded_products;  //leave this if we leave it as a function - we may port it all over to the template itself.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The part:

> array_merge($product_to_encode, $collection_to_encode);

won't work, because array_merge returns the merged array. In your case the merged array is not catched by a variable..

The following part should make it work:

> $collection_to_encode = array_merge($product_to_encode, $collection_to_encode);